# km to m for probability density

Tags: probability

If I have a density of $λ=30$ per $km^2$.

And a rectangular area that is $500$ m by $400$ m.

I need to find the probability distribution for $x$
(by multiplying the 3 numbers together)

But they are not in the same unit, the 'per square km' is really throwing me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one square kilometer is $1000000$ square meters. Know your unit conversion formulas.

By the way, since $500 * 400 = 200000$, the area is a fifth of a square kilometer.

Comment: thanks! Would I be better to change the 30 per sq km into meters? or the 400 and 500 into square km? I'm trying to use online conversions and its giving the equation that 30 per sq km is 3e+7? I just need 3 simple numbers to multiply together to give a decimal

Comment: I'm finding it difficult as I don't understand the equations. Are you not allowed to give answers on this? I've been stuck on this from this morning :(

Comment: can you help further?

Comment: @ShazzaNic 30 per sq kilometer times 1/5 square kilometer should be 6.

Comment: Also, people have other things to do other than just answering questions for the whole day. Be patient.

Comment: if I had this: 1.8 per square metre and area being 10m by 20m
I could do 1.8x10x20 = Poisson(360) so I need to do the same calculation only with the above being in the same units

Comment: @ShazzaNic You need to have the same units, yes. The answer should be Poisson(6) if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: i cant find a conversion online that lets me put square km into just m. It's only allowing me to put it into square metres and thats not what i need

Comment: @ShazzaNic You can't. That's squashing the 2d plane into a line. Area density is supposed to be in *square meters* (changed to area density because you're doing it on a plane)

Comment: what 3 numbers can I multiply together then? I can't get my head around this at all.

Comment: @ShazzaNic Oh, sorry. The *area* is 200,000 square meters, right? And, I think you divide by the density, not multiply...

Comment: maybe! Really not sure lol, awell thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed,
$$30km^{-2} = \frac{30}{1000^2m^2} = \frac{30}{1000000m^2} = \frac{3}{100000m^2} = 0.00003m^{-2} = 3 \times 10^{-5}m^{-2}.$$

Comment: @bounceback thank you. I am kind of following, still unsure how to make them all the same unit or what way would be better to do it.